# Beyond Code Expose | expose: command not found error in linux

Tags: composer-php, ngrok, localtunnel

I've composer installed in my linux machine. I wanted to use recently released tunnel application expose which is ngrok alternative.
check this [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tC4Q.png) . But after installing I cannot use it as it shows error expose: command not found. Someone posted similar issue [here](https://github.com/beyondcode/expose/issues/36) but I couldn't find any way to solve it. I tried checking path of composer ( given below ) and stuff but nothing happened.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

[image]

https://beyondco.de/docs/expose/introduction
[image]

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you added the proper paths to your `PATH`  variable?

Comment: I've added my environment file here. is it okay? point to note here, my composer is running fine in my machine working with bunch of laravel project currently.

Comment: @fahim152 I have added answer below I believe this can solve your issue :)

Comment: In my case I had to run `composer exec expose token [TOKEN HERE]` then `composer exec expose`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using a default terminal then :

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Alternative:

1. sudo nano ~/.bashrc
2. Add `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"` at the buttom.

Same Process if you use external terminal like **zshrc** as well.

Comment: yes!  this is the answer. However, I've already solved the issue. Appreciate it, brother :)

Comment: In my case I had to run `composer exec expose token [TOKEN HERE]` then `composer exec expose`

Comment: i got it working by adding `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"` i.e. composer folder was not inside config but on its own